# drawing a polygon with gdi+ and a vector of points

Tags: c++, gdi+

I have a vector of PointF's and I'm trying to draw a polygon with GDI+:

```
void Polygons::create_polygons(CDC& dc, std::array<Gdiplus::Color, 6>& cols)
{
    Gdiplus::Graphics gr{ dc };
    find_poly_vertices();
    Gdiplus::Pen pen{ Gdiplus::Color(255,0,0,0) };
    auto old_brush = dc.GetCurrentBrush();
    for (int i = 0; i != points.size(); ++i)
    {

        Gdiplus::SolidBrush br{ cols[i] };
        gr.DrawPolygon(&pen, points[i], points[i].size());
        gr.FillPolygon(&br, points[i], points[i].size());
    }
    dc.SelectObject(old_brush);
}
```

the find_poly_vertices() saves the points of the polygon in an array of vectors in     `Polygons`.

when I compile in visual studio I get error C2664:

```
cannot convert argument 2 from"std::vector<Gdiplus::PointF,std::allocator<_Ty>>" to "const Gdiplus::PointF *"
```

Comment: If you read the error, what do you *think* it means? What do you think might be a way to solve it?

Comment: @paddy thanks! std::vector::data() solved it

Comment: Baffles me that you would choose to show the function that _doesn't_ contain the error...

Comment: @paddy what do you mean? the line `gr.DrawPolygon(&pen, points[i], points[i].size());` and  `gr.FillPolygon(&br, points[i], points[i].size());` in this function are underlined

Comment: @AmerDakak For future questions, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Besides showing the full and complete error output, also add comments at the lines where the errors are.